# Show <div> on certain <td>

Tags: php, css, html-table

I want to show certain `<div>` on a certain `<td>` of a table. Here is what I'm trying in HTML:

```
<table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
    <tr>
        <td width="10%" valign="middle">{$avatar}{$change_avatar}</td>
        <td class="trow1" width="90%" valign="top">
            {$online_status}<span class="largetext"><strong>{$formattedname}</strong></span>
            <div class="smalltext">{$groupimage}</div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

On this code, I've this:

```
$change_avatar = '<div class="change_avatar"><a href="usercp.php?action=avatar">Change Avatar</a></div>';
```

I want to show `{$change_avatar}` on mouse hover when mouse comes over to the first `<td>` of the table, code I showed above.

Here is CSS I used;

```
.change_avatar{
    display: none;
    font-size: 11px;
    background: #363737;
    color: #FFF;
    opacity: 0.8;
    border-radius: 2px;
    padding: 3px 5px;
}

.change_avatar a:link, .change_avatar a:visited, .change_avatar a:active{
    color: #FFF !important;
    text-decoration: none;
}

td:hover .change_avatar{
    display: inline;
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-left: -70px;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Please help.

Comment: How many browsers was this tested in?

Comment: like this http://codepen.io/anon/pen/fIzDh ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

### CSS:

```
.change_avatar{
    display: none;
    font-size: 11px;
    background: #363737;
    color: #FFF;
    opacity: 0.8;
    border-radius: 2px;
    padding: 3px 5px;
}

.change_avatar a:link, .change_avatar a:visited, .change_avatar a:active{
    color: #FFF !important;
    text-decoration: none;
}

td #change_avatar:hover .change_avatar{
    display: inline;
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-left: -70px;
    position: absolute;
}
```

### HTML:

```
<table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
    <tr>
        <td width="10%" valign="middle" id="change_avatar">{$avatar}{$change_avatar}</td>
        <td class="trow1" width="90%" valign="top">
            {$online_status}<span class="largetext"><strong>{$formattedname}</strong></span>
            <div class="smalltext">{$groupimage}</div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score -3):

you can use JQuery to achieve this. e.g. you td have id="avatarTD"

```
$("#avatarTD").mouseover(function(){
    $(".change_avatar").show();
});

$("#avatarTD").mouseout(function(){
    $(".change_avatar").hide();
});
```

Comment: I really don't want to use jQuery for such a small thing, thanks for trying though